# Disk I/Os incurred by readLine () in Java

Tags: java, io

Does `readLine()` Java function used with `BufferedReader` cause one disk I/O per call?

If yes, is there any way to read specific number of lines, say n, from a text file causing only one disk I/O?

Here's the code:

```
String file;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (file));
int n = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    String line = br.readLine ();
    /* Do something */
}
```

Comment: Some (all, nowadays?) Operating Systems detect sequential reads, and arrange for asynchronous read-ahead, so that the data is already in memory when your program needs it.

Comment: @Ingo: while that's true, the last time I profiled it the process of getting data from the OS buffers and into a Java program was slow enough that using a BufferedReader or BufferedInputStream offered significant performance improvements even when data was being read directly from OS cache.

Comment: @Jules This is, of course true, and one could regard the data transfer between different address spaces as IO operation. I just wanted to point out another reason why the number of actual *disk accesses* is not necessarily correlated with the readLine() calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how big your lines are.

By default, `BufferedReader` uses an 8k buffer (see [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader)). This means that it will attempt to read 8K at a time from the `Reader`that it was constructed around. You can read as many lines as will fit into that 8K buffer, without going back to the underlying `Reader`.

---

Edit: As a general comment, *do not use `FileReader`*. Instead, wrap `FileInputStream` with an `InputStreamReader`, and *specify your encoding*.

Comment: parsifal: I didn't know how to add code in a comment, so edited the question with code. Now, as per the added code, how many disk reads will it cause, one for each line read (total 10) or only one in total?

Comment: @high5 - As I said, it depends on how big your lines are. If your lines are 10k apiece, it will make multiple calls to the `FileReader` for each line. If your lines are 10 bytes apiece, they'll all be fulfilled from the buffer, so you'll only hit the `FileReader` once.

Comment: parsifal: My one line is maximum 10 bytes, so it won't cause many disk reads. Thanks :)

Comment: parsifal: Could you please tell me the reason for using    FileInputStream instead of FileReader?

Comment: @high5: FileReader doesn't allow you to specify the encoding, and *encodings matter*.

Answer (score 5):

You are going through several layers of abstraction between the java code and the disk.  There is the Java Virtual Machine and its specific implementation, and then there is the operating system that the JVM is running on, which is then communicating to the disk through some method (it may be a network disk, it may be a local raid, it may be a solid state drive, it may be a stream from a network).

The specifics of the disk IO are determined by the virtual machine and operating system and the underlying source of the data.  It may be different for different vm's in how they ask for io requests - there is no way to determine this from within Java, nor is there a way to communicate at that level with the disk through Java.

Comment: Well, the actual problem is, I have to read some specified number of lines from a text file. So, I wondered if it is expensive in terms of disk I/Os to call readLine () that many times than calling some other function (if available) just once.

Comment: @high5 One can't say.  You may get different performance with the HotSPot JVM compared to the OpenJDK JVM.  You may get different performance on Windows compared to Linux.  You may get different performance with a file on the network than one locally.  Unless this performance is a real issue, don't worry about it.  If it is, then use profiler tools to identify the location of the performance bottlenecks and address it then.

Comment: +1 Also, the firmware on the drive's own internal controller board often does its own buffering.

Answer (score 1):

No.  A `BufferedReader` stores data in its internal buffer, that's the entire point of the class.  If there's enough data in there already, a call to `readLine()` will not issue another I/O request.